# Generic LINQ to SQL Extension Methods on collection of various derived types

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, extension-methods

I'm trying to create a generic extension method for an `IQueryable<T>`. T is an abstract `Player` and the IQueryable can contain concrete types `Goalkeeper` and `Striker`.

```
public abstract class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Fouls { get; set; }
}

public class Goalkeeper : Player
{
    public int Saves { get; set; }

}

public class Striker : Player
{
    public int Goals { get; set; }
}
```

The extension methods that are working (the simple ones) look like this:

```
public static IQueryable<Goalkeeper> NotPerforming(this IQueryable<Goalkeeper> goalkeepers)
{
    return goalkeepers.Where(g => g.Saves < goalkeepers.Average(x => x.Saves));
}

public static IQueryable<Striker> NotPerforming(this IQueryable<Striker> strikers)
{
    return strikers.Where(g => g.Goals < strikers.Average(x => x.Goals));
}
```

Which I can use like this:

```
var badGoalies = players.OfType<Goalkeeper>().NotPerforming();
var badStrikers = players.OfType<Striker>().NotPerforming();
```

So now I want to query **for all players** who are not performing well.

```
var badPlayers = players.NotPerforming();
```

Which I can't seem to get to work properly.

```
public static IQueryable<T> NotPerforming<T>(this IQueryable<T> players)
    where T : Player
{
    // what to do here?
}
```

I tried things like...

```
return players.OfType<Striker>().NotPerforming()
          .Union(
              players.OfType<Goalkeeper>().NotPerforming()
          );
```

Which doesn't work.

What is the best practice way of doing this -- and without leaving LINQ-to-SQL because I'd like to keep chaining extension methods -- and keeping good performance in mind?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another extension method and put there a logic:

```
public static IQueryable<Player> NotPerforming(this IQueryable<Player> players)
{
    var notPerformingGoalKeepers = players.NotPerformingGoalkeepers();
    var notPerformingStrikers = players.NotPerformingStrikers();

    return notPerformingGoalKeepers.Cast<Player>()
        .Concat(notPerformingStrikers);
}

public static IQueryable<Goalkeeper> NotPerformingGoalkeepers(this IQueryable<Player> players)
{
    var goalkeepers = players.OfType<Goalkeeper>();
    return goalkeepers.Where(g => g.Saves < goalkeepers.Average(x => x.Saves));
}

public static IQueryable<Striker> NotPerformingStrikers(this IQueryable<Player> players)
{
    var strikers = players.OfType<Striker>();
    return strikers.Where(g => g.Goals < strikers.Average(x => x.Goals));
}
```

And use:

```
var badPlayers = players.NotPerforming();
```

***Or another approach:***

```
public static IQueryable<Player> NotPerforming<T>(this IQueryable<Player> players) where T : Player
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Goalkeeper))
    {
        return players.OfType<Goalkeeper>().NotPerforming();
    }

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Striker))
    {
        return players.OfType<Striker>().NotPerforming();
    }

    return null;
}

private static IQueryable<Goalkeeper> NotPerforming(this IQueryable<Goalkeeper> goalkeepers)
{
    return goalkeepers.Where(g => g.Saves < goalkeepers.Average(x => x.Saves));
}

private static IQueryable<Striker> NotPerforming(this IQueryable<Striker> strikers)
{
    return strikers.Where(g => g.Goals < strikers.Average(x => x.Goals));
}
```

And use:

```
var badStrikers = players.NotPerforming<Striker>();
var badGoalkeepers = players.NotPerforming<Goalkeeper>();

var badPlayers = players.NotPerforming<Striker>()
    .Concat(players.NotPerforming<Goalkeeper>());
```